# Field source tokens for media items like image field

Tags: datasource

I have been using tokens for a while, patching in a processor to the `getLookupSourceItems` pipelines and transforming a token like `$siteName$` into the site name. Or $site$ into the the current sites root path.

But in field sources for media items like an image field, this pipeline is never hit. I would like to replace the $siteName with the current site's name. This isn't rendering datasources. This is a template's field source.

I get the following error since my field source is not transformed.

> The source of this Image field points to an item that does not exist.

`/sitecore/media library/Images/$siteName`  would become `/sitecore/media library/Images/SiteA`

Any thoughts on what pipeline is controlling media field sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but a common way of doing what you are asking is to implement your own image field control. You basically override `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Image` and override the `Source` property and replace the token at that point.

There is an example of this found at [How to change the source from an image field programmatically?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6118/how-to-change-the-source-from-an-image-field-programmatically)

Comment: This is really some heavy lifting to tokenize the datasource for an image. But it looks right.

Comment: It's definitely non-trivial, but it's also fairly boilerplate and doesn't require much customization between implementations, so you can basically re-use it directly.