# Solve copy and paste image path

Tags: media-library, fieldtype

I created a custom image field, so far its working fine. but when I take an image path and add it manually to the field without clicking browse. It disappears which is not the normal behavior in OOTB image field.

[image]

**Custom Image Field Class:**

```
public class CustomImage : Image
{
    public string ItemID
    {
        get
        {
            return base.GetViewStateString("ItemID");
        }
        set
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(value, "ItemID");
            base.SetViewStateString("ItemID", value);
        }
    }

    public string FieldID
    {
        get
        {
            return base.GetViewStateString("FieldID");
        }
        set
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(value, "FieldID");
            base.SetViewStateString("FieldID", value);
        }
    }

    public override string Source
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetViewStateString(nameof(Source));
        }
        set
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)value, nameof(value));

            string str = MainUtil.UnmapPath(value);
            if (str.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
            {
                str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                var item = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(new ID(ItemID));
                str = Query(value, item);
            }
            this.SetViewStateString(nameof(Source), str);
        }
    }

    public override void HandleMessage(Message message)
    {
        if (message["id"] != base.ID)
            return;

        if (message.Name.Equals("contentimage:customimage"))
        {
            Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "HandleCustomImage");
        }

        base.HandleMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share code of your custom image field?

Comment: @grg the same steps as the answer in this question  https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6118/how-to-change-the-source-from-an-image-field-programmatically

Comment: Please post the code you have written for this custom field

Comment: @AhmedOkour I added the custom field code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in calling the base function, it suppose to be in the beginning of the fuction.

```
public override void HandleMessage(Message message)
    {
        base.HandleMessage(message);

        if (message.Name.Equals("contentimage:customimage"))
        {
            Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "HandleCustomImage");
        }
    }
```