# Custom field type has empty string for FieldTypeKey in RenderPipelineArgs; how to populate?

Tags: custom-field, renderfield

I'm creating a custom field type for our responsive image implementation in Sitecore 10.1 and I need a way to display the image using `Html.Sitecore().Field("field_name")`. I think I'm mostly there but I'm stuck on getting the renderField pipeline to recognize when it's dealing with my custom field type.

The work I've done borrows heavily from the native `ImageRenderer` class and `GetImageFieldValues` processor on the pipeline, and the way they handle that is to check `args.FieldTypeKey` for a value of "image." Unfortunately, that property is an empty string for my custom field and I can't figure out how to get a value in there.

Does anyone know **how to populate the RenderPipelineArgs.FieldTypeKey value for a custom field type?** Or, alternatively, can anyone **suggest a different method for my renderField processor to identify when the field is my custom type?**

I can add a field of my custom type to a data template and the control for it renders correctly in Content Editor (i.e., it uses a modified droptree and that functions as expected to select a value). But when I attempt to view the page (Editing mode, Preview mode, or live site) the field isn't included in the rendering.

### What I've done so far

1. Created a custom field type in the core database under sitecore/system/Field Types/Custom Fields
2. Created a class in my project (`ResponsiveImage.cs`) to implement the field, and set the Assembly and Class properties of the custom field type to point to it
3. Created a custom RenderFieldPipeline processor (`GetResponsiveImageFieldValue.cs`) to render the field and a config file (`ResponsiveImage.config`) to add it to the `renderField` pipeline
4. Added an entry in the `<fieldTypes>` config node for my custom field type
5. Published everything

### Code

`GetResponsiveImageFieldValue.cs`

```
public class GetResponsiveImageFieldValue
{
    public virtual void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));
        if (!IsResponsiveImage(args)) return;

        ResponsiveImageRenderer renderer = this.CreateRenderer();
        ConfigureRenderer(args, renderer);
        SetRenderFieldResults(renderer.Render(), args);
    }

    protected virtual bool IsResponsiveImage(RenderFieldArgs args) => args.FieldTypeKey == "responsive image";

    protected virtual ResponsiveImageRenderer CreateRenderer() => new ResponsiveImageRenderer();

    protected virtual void ConfigureRenderer(RenderFieldArgs args, ResponsiveImageRenderer renderer)
    {
        renderer.Item = args.Item;
    }

    protected virtual void SetRenderFieldResults(RenderFieldResult result, RenderFieldArgs args)
    {
        args.Result.FirstPart = result.FirstPart;
        args.Result.LastPart = result.LastPart;
        args.WebEditParameters.AddRange(args.Parameters);
        args.DisableWebEditContentEditing = true;
        args.DisableWebEditFieldWrapping = true;
        args.WebEditClick =
            "return Sitecore.WebEdit.editControl($JavascriptParameters, \"webedit:chooseresponsiveimage\")";
    }
}
```

`ResponsiveImages.config`

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore>
    <commands>
      <command name="webedit:chooseresponsiveimage" type="Sitecore.MyCompany.Foundation.MVC.CustomSitecore.ChooseResponsiveImage, Sitecore.MyCompany.Foundation.MVC" />
    </commands>
    <overrideXmlControls>
      <override xmlControl="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.ResponsiveMediaBrowser" with="/sitecore/client/applications/Dialogs/SelectResponsiveMediaDialog" />
    </overrideXmlControls>
    <pipelines>
      <renderField>
        <processor type="Sitecore.MyCompany.Foundation.MVC.Pipelines.GetResponsiveImageFieldValue, Sitecore.MyCompany.Foundation.MVC" 
                   patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.MyCompany.Foundation.MVC.Pipelines.CustomGetImageFieldValue, Sitecore.MyCompany.Foundation.MVC']" />
      </renderField>
    </pipelines>
    <fieldTypes>
      <fieldType name="Responsive Image" type="Sitecore.MyCompany.Foundation.MVC.CustomFields.ResponsiveImage, Sitecore.MyCompany.Foundation.MVC" />
    </fieldTypes>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

*(Note: opted to not include a listing of ResponsiveImage.cs because it just extends our modified droptree class and overwrites the Source property, and it should be irrelevant to the problem at hand.)*

### Similar SO questions

The only existing question I could find that comes close to this is: [How to change the source from an image field programmatically?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6118/how-to-change-the-source-from-an-image-field-programmatically/6125#6125)

The answers to that come very close to where my problem is but don't quite address the `FieldTypeKey` field itself.

Answer (score 4):

#### Quick answer

---

You can populate it in the field `"Type"` of your template's field item.

Still confusing?

Here is an image to help you

[image]

The image above shows how the type is set in the default image field, pay attention the `RawValues` is checked, it's just a text value, go to your field item and add the value you want.

If you uncheck raw values to see if your custom field is being shown as an option in the Droplist you should make sure you have a FieldType item created under `"/sitecore/system/Field types"` in core database.

#### Detailed answer

---

Firstly, do you really need a custom field type?

If what you need is to change the rendered HTML for image fields, all you need is a pipeline processor.

Some advice:

1. Pay attention to the processor's invoking order
2. Disable all other processors for a while

So, to me your best option is extending the `GetImageFieldValue` processor and make it recognize your custom field type.

So let's make a few changes.

**The processor**

```
    public class GetResponsiveImageFieldValue : GetImageFieldValue
    {
        public virtual void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));
            if (!this.ShouldExecute(args)) return;

            base.Process(args);
        }

        public bool ShouldExecute(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            if(!this.IsImage(args))
                return false;
            if (!Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal)
                return false;
            if (Sitecore.Context.Site == null)
                return false;
            if (Sitecore.Context.Item == null)
                return false;
            if (args.Result != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Result.FirstPart))
                return false;


            return true;
        }


        protected override bool IsImage(RenderFieldArgs args) => args.FieldTypeKey == "image" || args.FieldTypeKey == "responsive image";
    }
```

**The config patch**

```
    <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
      <sitecore>
          <pipelines>
              <renderField>
                  <processor patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="Sitecore.MyCompany.Foundation.MVC.Pipelines.GetResponsiveImageFieldValue, Sitecore.MyCompany.Foundation.MVC"/>
              </renderField>
          </pipelines>
      </sitecore>
    </configuration>
```

And the last but not least, if at some point you need to bring images from `Content Hub` you'll probably have to change your approach.

My main question for you is, do you really need a custom field?
If the answer for that is no, a new processor for `RenderField` pipeline is enough.

[This article](https://www.andreandrade.blog/2023/02/renderfield-pipeline-getimagefieldvalue.html) is about an issue related to RenderField pipeline and a ContentHub instance, it might give you some insights.